# How can I hide particular words in a PDF on Android?

Tags: android, pdf, cpu-word, document

I am trying to implement reading a PDF within an Android app. I want to hide particular words from it.

I have downloaded a PDF viewer library. It opens properly but am not sure whether it is possible to hide words in that document.

Is there any library available that can do this?

Please help me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope this question is related with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686923/android-hide-particular-words-in-pdf

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using muPDF Library and seriously muPDF or other libraries which renders PDF uses Images for rendering data they are not in text format so the modifications you want will be pretty hard to do so.

You may use iText Library for this, itext Library can extract the text from PDF and then you show the text as you want.